# Clojurescript with webpack and infer-externs requires undefined object with advanced compilation

Tags: webpack, compilation, clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I followed this guide on using webpack + clojurescript, https://clojurescript.org/guides/webpack. It *works perfectly* when compiled with `:none` or `:whitespace`, but when I compile with `:advanced` one of the objects hooked to the `window` ends up being imported as an undefined object, causing the app to crash.

I tried a couple of things, like defining and `externs.js` with the window object, but I find it hard to dig deeper on this.

This is my compiler arguments:

```clj
{:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "env/prod/cljs"]
             :compiler
             {:output-to     "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js"
              :output-dir    "target/cljsbuild/public/js"
              :source-map    "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js.map"
              :optimizations :advanced
              :infer-externs true
              :pretty-print  false
              :npm-deps      false
              :foreign-libs [{:file "dist/index_bundle.js"
                              :provides ["react" "react-dom" "react-select" "react-table"]
                              :global-exports {react React
                                               react-dom ReactDOM
                                               react-select Select
                                               react-table ReactTable}}]}}
```

This is my index.js, entrypoint for webpack

```js
// Here we define what we need.
// Webpack is gonna use this and produce a bundle.
// cljs will read this bundle and provide the namespaces for us.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'

window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
window.Select = Select;
window.ReactTable = ReactTable
```

The webpack config is as simple as

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    }
}
```

The error I get is because on a file like this:

```clj
(ns foo
  (:require
   [react-table :as ReactTable]
   [reagent.core :as r]
   [clojure.string :as str]))
[...]
(r/adapt-react-class ReactTable)
```

ReactTable is bound to `nil`. I can confirm that on the js console `window.ReactTable` is also `nil`.

Simply changing `:advanced` to `:whitespace` on the compiler opts, and leaving everything else as-is, solves the issue. And in the js console, `window.ReactTable` is no longer `nil`.

Any ideas? :)

----- EDIT (adding workaround info) --------

I found that a possible work-around for this use case is to "split" the `foreign-libs` like this:

```
              :foreign-libs [{:file "dist/main.js"
                              :provides ["react" "react-dom" "react-select"]
                              :global-exports {react React
                                               react-dom ReactDOM
                                               react-select Select}}
                             {:file "dist/react_table.js"
                              :requires ["react" "react-dom"]
                              :provides ["react-table"]
                              :global-exports {react-table ReactTable}}]}}
```

adapting the webpack config to and entrypoints create two separate bundles, one with only `ReactTable` and the other with all others. I don't consider this to be a solution because the real problem was not identified. But doing so solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you're getting issues with advanced optimizations messing up with the names of the libraries you are using, but *depending on your use case, you may not need to use Webpack at all* (not sure if this is an option for you).

It seems the libraries you're using are popular enough to be covered under the [CLJSJS project](https://cljsjs.github.io/), so that if you find the versions that you need, you can add the  libraries as regular dependencies in your `project.clj` file and it should just work. The packages from CLJSJS include the dependency information and the externs files conveniently packaged.

Finally, you may have stumbled in a bug in an older version of ClojureScript. Check if you are using the most recent version, or maybe one that is a bit older.

Comment: Hi @Denis, I wanted to use webpack to have more control on the versions of the third party libraries, and also because I wanted to see it working (hehe). Furthermore, I wanted flexibility to use less known npm packages someday. Regarding the version, I'm using "1.10.520". I have also tried some previous versions thinking that it could have been a regression, but I had no luck.

Comment: I edited the post adding a possible workaround I found, but still I have no idea why the original setup does not work.